# How to get VS ASP.NET unit testing to work?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write a few test for an aspx page that handles posted xml.
The project runs fine on the visual studio's web development server (WebDev.WebServer40) but when I try to run a basic (empty) test like the one bellow, the test run results show me this error:

```
The host type 'ASP.NET' cannot be loaded for the following reason: The key 'ASP.NET' cannot be found.
```

I've tried all I could think of, but no go.

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("D:\\Documents\\Projects\\Web\\Osc.Framework\\", "/")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:24811/Default.aspx")]
public void Page_LoadTest()
{
    Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: My solution was related to David's answer and http://stackoverflow.com/a/25180882/892327

Answer (score 4):

Open the test settings you're using (Menu->Test->Edit Test Settings->{Your Test Settings}). Go to the "Hosts" property page. For the setting "Run tests in 32 or 64-bit process", set it to "Force tests to run in a 32-bit process".