# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I got the same problem like here [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829419/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-web-pageinspector-loader/41169236#41169236) but not on my development machine but on hosting server.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

I was able to fix it by adding below code to my web.config

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5"> 
    <assemblies> 
        <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader,
    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies> 
</compilation>
```

or by removing reference to this assembly from web.config files in framework directories.

I never installed VS there and i never had PageInspector installed there. Any idea why those configs reference them?

Comment: Is the assembly in the bin folder on the hosting server? If not, in VS, find the assembly in your project bin folder, highlight it, and choose "Copy Local" in the properties window. Then be sure to copy it to the hosting server.

Comment: i'm not using page inspector. It's referenced by the framework configs not by my project.

Comment: VS must have added it when you created the project. It does that according to project type. Just remove it if you're not going to use it.

Comment: did you read my post? It was on clear hosting machine without any trace of VS.