# Visual studio 2017 installer opens in taskbar but does not show

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 Community edition on my Dell laptop running Windows 10 64-bit. I download the community web installer and run the .exe file. The program shows it's extracting some files, then asks for admin permission, which I give yes, and then I only get an icon on the taskbar as shown in the picture below. It does not seem to run or anything. Even opening a second instance comes to the same dead end.

[image: Vs taskbar icon]

[image: Vs empty window]

I have also tried offline installation by downloading the files via command prompt. But again after one stage, the process opens this installer.exe file and comes to the same dead end.

I am not sure if I am missing any other installations, or any other supporting libraries are corrupted. I have searched in other forums where they suggest the problem occurring due to multiple display setup or dual graphics adapter, but my setup is nothing like that. I have only Intel HD graphics running on my laptop monitor.

I need VS 2017 badly and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I was able to run the visual studio installer somehow by changing the setup.exe to run in Windows 8 compatible setting. Now, after installing, if I run the VS 2017 application, I am getting the same kind of problem. I only get an icon on the taskbar, I dont get any VS 2017 Window.

After googling, I found a way to get the log file when the application starts. The xml document indicates 4 errors on startup. Looks like some components are unable to be loaded. I have no idea why. I am attaching the screenshot here of the log file showing the 4 errors. The entire log file - [VS 2017 log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkhceuhww28l8fx/MyVSLog.xml?dl=0)

[image: VS 2017 launch log]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, no. I am only using a direct connection.

Comment: Did you check [the VS2017 troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017)? I would have a look in the event log. [Assembling all the log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017#how-to-get-visual-studio-installation-logs) would be the first thing I would do. Are you sure your account is an admin account by the way? With rights to elevate to "real" admin rights?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, Yes, I am running on an admin account. As for the log files, I have edited the problem now that I was able to run setup, but stuck in opening the application. I have attached the errors snap above and also the log file when opening VS 2017.

Comment: Don't have time to look at this. Let me lob some suggestions? Might not be very helpful, but here goes: I would try another computer if you can, **even a virtual**. Install minimally if so - just get a heartbeat first. You can also try installing as a different admin user on the box, but in your case that will almost certainly not work (can sort out profile-related issues and other nuisances). Any other people with Visual Studio in the office? Did you call support and ask about what .NET policies are in effect on the systems?

Comment: MEF = [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensibility_Framework). Could be something messed up with .NET, could be a [dirty machine from beta versions / other editions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829419/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-web-pageinspector-loader), could be lots of things. Try that virtual if you can? I know it stinks, but you get some very good benefits too (like when upgrades cause you massive problems all of a sudden - quick revert available).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, Thanks for your suggestion. Virtual box approach could have worked but I figured that its high time that I reinnstall my windows as there were other problems which I couldnt troubleshoot for a long time and now I am able to launch VS 2017 without any problems. But I am not sure what was wrong earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem of mine by re-installing the windows. I don't know what was the root cause of the problem earlier but I had other features like VPN not working properly in my OS so I figured that its high time I do it.

Comment: Great call, I think you solved a lot of problems like that (and got a few new ones that are manageable). As the saying goes: for minor problems reboot, for major problems rebuild. A problem removed are sometimes 10 problems solved. For now :-) - (been around for a while). Windows should offer a "revert to pristine" option so we could rebuild Windows without touching any data, but that is an entirely different matter.