# Deploy ASP.NET MVC5 to IIS7 assembly not Found

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, .net-assembly

Publishing a MVC5-Project with VisualStudio2015 works fine, all files are created in a folder and the .dll appears in the subfolder /bin. I set up the project with a new ApplicationPool in my IIS7, connect with the created folder and start it . Now I get the message

> file or assembly not found at  /MyFolder.

When I look at the temporary files of the application (path is given in the error message), there is none.

Why does the IIS not find the assemblies in the publishing Folder?

The first assembly that is mentioned in the error message is a custom assembly which is added to the References of the MVC5 project.

Should I add the custom assemblies via Web.Release.config? How?

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem.
Open the ApplicationPool in the IIS7, then right-click on the name of the website -> advanced settings -> Enable-32-bit-Applications = true

[[Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. The issue is random, but after it happens once, it continues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096225/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access-is-denied-th][1]) answered by Fragment