# Changed web.config file after access WCF service not working in https and throw error "Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_e_nyphyd"

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, https, web-config

We have configured WCF web service with the "web.config" file for HTTPS. it is working fine, but when changing anything "web.config" file after accessing WCF web service from hosted server IIS then the following error throws as shown in the image. Again publish then it works until anything changes in "web.config" file from IIS.

[image]

We would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it a web app with purely WCF bits or a mixture of WCF and ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: It is a mixture of WCF and ASP.NET webForms.

Comment: So when you change the web.config you get this error. You can try the solution shared by multiple community members under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096225/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access-is-denied-th).